# Union of three events with unknowns

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the next problem:

---

Given events A,B,C suth that A$\subset$B, B$\cap$C=$\emptyset$, Pr(A)=0.2, Pr(B)=0.4, P(C)=0.3

Compute Pr(A$\cup$B$\cup$C)

---

The formula to find A$\cup$B$\cup$C is:

Pr(A$\cup$B$\cup$C)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)+Pr(C)-Pr(A$\cap$B)-Pr(B$\cap$C)-Pr(A$\cap$C)+Pr(A$\cap$B$\cap$C)

I can derive:

Pr(A$\cap$B)=Pr(A)=0.2 since A$\subset$B

Pr(B$\cap$C)=0 since B$\cap$C=$\emptyset$

How to find Pr(A$\cap$C) and Pr(A$\cap$B$\cap$C) to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Make sure to write 'compute $P(A\cup B \cup C) $' rather than 'compute $A\cup B \cup C $'

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy  Will do it
But I just copy description from my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A\cap C \subseteq B\cap C=\emptyset$ so $A\cap C$ and $A \cap B \cap C$ are both empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a mistake. After I draw a Venn diagram it started to be very clear

Answer (score 0):

Using a Karnaugh table gives a global view and is considered as a valid auxiliary item for a proof.

[image]

The first condition $A \subset B \iff A \cap \overline{B}=\varnothing$ is rendered as two void sets with a red bar. Then two other void sets account for property $B \cap C=\varnothing$.

Then the rest is straightforward:

$$0.2+x=0.4 \ \ \text{and} \ \ y=0.3$$

Adding:

$$P(A \cup B \cup C)=0.2+x+y=0.7$$

Comment: Hi @Jean Marie
Thank you very much for your explanation. Unfortunately, I cannot vote up since I do not have enough reputation